# Why newly created mirror repository is not working as source one

Tags: centos, yum, repository

I'm using RockyLinux 8.5 on my test server and i want to create local repository for some applications as i won't have internet access in real case, only local repos.

I've downloaded package with it's dependencies using

```
yumdownloader --installroot=/tmp/empty --resolve ipa-client --destdir ~/.
```

Then I use `createrepo_c` `modifyrepo_c`  to create /repodata.

But when I'm trying to install ipa-client from this repo, I get errors that don't occur when using a remote repository:

```
Error: 
 Problem: problem with installed package authselect-compat-1.2.2-3.el8.x86_64
  - package authselect-compat-1.2.2-3.el8.x86_64 requires authselect(x86-64) = 1.2.2-3.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both authselect-1.2.5-2.el8_7.x86_64 and authselect-1.2.2-3.el8.x86_64
  - package ipa-client-4.9.10-9.module+el8.7.0+1120+659f71b8.x86_64 requires authselect >= 1.2.5, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - package authselect-1.2.2-3.el8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

which brings me to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just used `yum install ipa-client --allowerasing`, look for packages with problems, downloaded them with `yumdownloader --resolve` one by one and add them to repository.

I dont know why, but `yumdownloader --installroot=/tmp/empty --resolve ipa-client --destdir ~/.` just didn't download all dependencies.